# How to fix java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month error?

Tags: oracle, spring-mvc, mybatis

I have an application that needs to generate a report, I can generate a part of the report but when I repeat the method I used, I get this error.

ERROR I get:

```
; SQL []; ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
] with root cause
 Error : 1847, Position : 615, Sql = SELECT * FROM MONTH_REF r LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        count(case when i.NOOFMINS > 5 THEN ID END) as COUNT_SUSTAINED,
        COALESCE(SUM(case when i.NOOFMINS > 5 THEN i.NOOFCONS END),0) as NOOFCONS_SUSTAINED,
        COALESCE(SUM(case when i.NOOFMINS > 5 THEN i.NOOFMINS END),0)as NOOFMINS_SUSTAINED,
        count(case when i.NOOFMINS <= 5 THEN i.ID END) as COUNT_MOMENTARY,
        COALESCE(SUM(case when i.NOOFMINS <= 5 THEN i.NOOFCONS END),0) as NOOFCONS_MOMENTARY,
        TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(i.TIME_OFF,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MON') as TIME_OFF_MONTH
        FROM INTERRUPTIONS i
        WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIME_OFF,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY') = :1 
        AND i.ISOLATINGDEVICE_CODE != '203' AND i.DELETED = '0'
        AND i.CAUSE_CODE != '003' AND i.CAUSE_CODE != '004' AND i.CAUSE_CODE != '008'
        AND (trim(i.FEEDER) = :2  or i.FEEDER LIKE ('FEEDERS %2%'))
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(i.TIME_OFF,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MON')) TIME_OFF_COUNTS ON r."MONTH" = TIME_OFF_COUNTS."TIME_OFF_MONTH" 
        ORDER BY TO_DATE(r."MONTH",'MON') asc, OriginalSql = SELECT * FROM MONTH_REF r LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        count(case when i.NOOFMINS > 5 THEN ID END) as COUNT_SUSTAINED,
        COALESCE(SUM(case when i.NOOFMINS > 5 THEN i.NOOFCONS END),0) as NOOFCONS_SUSTAINED,
        COALESCE(SUM(case when i.NOOFMINS > 5 THEN i.NOOFMINS END),0)as NOOFMINS_SUSTAINED,
        count(case when i.NOOFMINS <= 5 THEN i.ID END) as COUNT_MOMENTARY,
        COALESCE(SUM(case when i.NOOFMINS <= 5 THEN i.NOOFCONS END),0) as NOOFCONS_MOMENTARY,
        TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(i.TIME_OFF,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MON') as TIME_OFF_MONTH
        FROM INTERRUPTIONS i
        WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIME_OFF,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY') = ?
        AND i.ISOLATINGDEVICE_CODE != '203' AND i.DELETED = '0'
        AND i.CAUSE_CODE != '003' AND i.CAUSE_CODE != '004' AND i.CAUSE_CODE != '008'
        AND (trim(i.FEEDER) = ? or i.FEEDER LIKE ('FEEDERS %2%'))
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(i.TIME_OFF,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MON')) TIME_OFF_COUNTS ON r."MONTH" = TIME_OFF_COUNTS."TIME_OFF_MONTH" 
        ORDER BY TO_DATE(r."MONTH",'MON') asc, Error Msg = ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:747)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3887)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1079)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:83)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:148)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6457.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:230)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:137)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:75)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6487.getFeederReliability(Unknown Source)
    at com.beneco.cwms.web.OmsReportController.feederRlbltyPrint(OmsReportController.java:945)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

CONTROLLER (SEE COMMENTS)

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/oms/omsReports/omsPrint/rlbltyFeeder"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String feederRlbltyPrint(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "year", required = true) String year) {
List<FeederReliability> feederListF1 = omsReportsMapper.getFeederReliability(year,"Feeder 1", "1");//working
List<FeederReliability> feederListF1Qtr = omsReportsMapper.getFeederReliabilityQtr(year,"Feeder 1", "1");//working
List<FeederReliability> feederListF2 = omsReportsMapper.getFeederReliability(year,"Feeder 2", "2");//when this is executed, the error appears, but when I comment it out, it works!

model.addAttribute("feederListF1",feederListF1);
        model.addAttribute("feederListF1Qtr",feederListF1Qtr);
        model.addAttribute("feederListF2",feederListF2);

return "oms/omsReports/omsPrint/rlbltyFeeder";
    }
```

MAPPER XML

```
<select id="getFeederReliability" parameterType="map" resultMap="feederRlbltyList">
        SELECT * FROM MONTH_REF r LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        count(case when i.NOOFMINS &gt; 5 THEN ID END) as COUNT_SUSTAINED,
        COALESCE(SUM(case when i.NOOFMINS &gt; 5 THEN i.NOOFCONS END),0) as NOOFCONS_SUSTAINED,
        COALESCE(SUM(case when i.NOOFMINS &gt; 5 THEN i.NOOFMINS END),0)as NOOFMINS_SUSTAINED,
        count(case when i.NOOFMINS &lt;= 5 THEN i.ID END) as COUNT_MOMENTARY,
        COALESCE(SUM(case when i.NOOFMINS &lt;= 5 THEN i.NOOFCONS END),0) as NOOFCONS_MOMENTARY,
        TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(i.TIME_OFF,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MON') as TIME_OFF_MONTH
        FROM INTERRUPTIONS i
        WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIME_OFF,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY') = #{year}
        AND i.ISOLATINGDEVICE_CODE != '203' AND i.DELETED = '0'
        AND i.CAUSE_CODE != '003' AND i.CAUSE_CODE != '004' AND i.CAUSE_CODE != '008'
        AND (trim(i.FEEDER) = #{feeder} or i.FEEDER LIKE ('FEEDERS %${feederNo}%'))
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(i.TIME_OFF,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MON')) TIME_OFF_COUNTS ON r."MONTH" = TIME_OFF_COUNTS."TIME_OFF_MONTH" 
        ORDER BY TO_DATE(r."MONTH",'MON') asc
    </select>
```

I don't know what's the problem with this, I have searched every but I can't seem to find any solution.

I hope you guys could help!

Comment: Most likely you have bad data in one of the TO_DATE functions.  You will have to strip down your query and remove parts until, then add back sections until you find the problematic clause.

Comment: @OldProgrammer That's what I think too! I'll try to check the data again, It's the third time lol. Hope someone could give their insights on this one. thanks dude!

Comment: @PatrickBrianGarcia As the error says that 'Position : 615', wrong data may be in INTERRUPTIONS.TIME_OFF. If I am right, this query will fail with the same error `SELECT TO_DATE(TIME_OFF,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM INTERRUPTIONS`. Then you can do binary-search to find the row.